# SQL Server: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to check if the columns of a table contain null value and if so assign the 0 value. I had problem because there where UniqueIdentifier column existing. So I change my code to assign '0' value. But now I have a problem when there is DateTime column.
Here is the code:

```
Select @sql = @sql + 'Case when IsNull(i.[' + Column_Name +  
'],''0'') = IsNull(d.[' + Column_name + '],''0'') then ''''  
 else ' + quotename(Column_Name, char(39)) + ' + '',''' + ' end +' 
from information_schema.columns  
where table_name = 'Users' and column_name <>'rowguid' and column_name <>'modifieddate'
```

Another failed attempt:

```
Select @sql = @sql + 
    'Case 
        when IsDate(i.['+Column_Name+']) =1 and IsDate(d.['+Column_Name+']) =1  and IsNull(i.[' + Column_Name +  '],1/1/1900) = IsNull(d.[' + Column_name + '],1/1/1900)
        then ''''
        when IsNull(i.[' + Column_Name +  '],''0'') = IsNull(d.[' + Column_name + '],''0'') 
        then ''''  
        else ' + quotename(Column_Name, char(39)) + ' + '',''' + ' end +' 
from information_schema.columns  
where table_name = 'Users' and column_name <>'rowguid' and column_name <>'modifieddate'
```

Full code:

```
if @Action = 'U'
BEGIN
Select @sql = @sql + 
    'Case when IsNull(i.[' + Column_Name +  
'],' + CASE DATA_TYPE
         WHEN 'int' THEN '0'
         WHEN 'bigint' THEN '0'
         WHEN 'tinyint' THEN '0'
         WHEN 'uniqueidentifier' THEN '''0'''
         WHEN 'varchar' THEN CHAR(39) + '-' + CHAR(39)
         WHEN 'nvarchar' THEN CHAR(39) + '-' + CHAR(39)
         WHEN 'date' THEN CHAR(39) + '1/1/1900' + CHAR(39)
         WHEN 'datetime' THEN CHAR(39) + '1/1/1900 00:00:00' + CHAR(39)
         ELSE ''
       END + ') = IsNull(d.[' + Column_name + '],'+
       CASE DATA_TYPE
         WHEN 'int' THEN '0'
         WHEN 'bigint' THEN '0'
         WHEN 'tinyint' THEN '0'
         WHEN 'uniqueidentifier' THEN '''0'''
         WHEN 'varchar' THEN CHAR(39) + '-' + CHAR(39)
         WHEN 'nvarchar' THEN CHAR(39) + '-' + CHAR(39)
         WHEN 'date' THEN CHAR(39) + '1/1/1900' + CHAR(39)
         WHEN 'datetime' THEN CHAR(39) + '1/1/1900 00:00:00' + CHAR(39)
         ELSE ''
       END + ') then ''''  
 else ' + quotename(Column_Name, char(39)) + ' + '',''' + ' end +'
from information_schema.columns  
where table_name = 'Users' and column_name <>'rowguid' and column_name <>'modifieddate'
--Define output parameter 
set @ParmDefinition = '@OutString varchar(max) OUTPUT' 
--Format sql 
set @sql = 'Select @OutString = '  
+ Substring(@sql,1 , len(@sql) -1) +  
' From dbo.Users i  ' --Will need to be updated for target schema 
+ ' inner join #tempTrigT d on 
i.id = d.id'  --Will need to be updated for target schema 
--Execute sql and retrieve desired column list in output parameter 
exec sp_executesql @sql, @ParmDefinition, @OutString OUT
```

Comment: You will have to pick a more suitable default value - a date.

Comment: I want to be dynamic because there are different columns (int, datetime, GUID etc)

Comment: What the database allows is more relevant than what you want.

Comment: so is it possible to check if is datetime then assign a default date value otherwise assign '0'?

Comment: Then you should add a case which checks your data type and in case of "date" or "datetime" use '1900-01-01' or similar...

Comment: @Tyron78 can you propose a solution with the way I can achieve that?

Comment: The information_schema.columns features a column named DATA_TYPE, right? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example how a corresponding CASE might look like -however, it is NOT complete and you might want to extend / redesign it a little:

```
Select @sql = @sql + 'Case when IsNull(i.[' + Column_Name +  
'],' + CASE DATA_TYPE
         WHEN 'int' THEN '0'
         WHEN 'bigint' THEN '0'
         WHEN 'tinyint' THEN '0'
         WHEN 'varchar' THEN CHAR(39) + '-' + CHAR(39)
         WHEN 'nvarchar' THEN CHAR(39) + '-' + CHAR(39)
         WHEN 'date' THEN CHAR(39) + '1900-01-01' + CHAR(39)
         ELSE ''
       END + ') = IsNull(d.[' + Column_name + '],'+
       CASE DATA_TYPE
         WHEN 'int' THEN '0'
         WHEN 'bigint' THEN '0'
         WHEN 'tinyint' THEN '0'
         WHEN 'varchar' THEN CHAR(39) + '-' + CHAR(39)
         WHEN 'nvarchar' THEN CHAR(39) + '-' + CHAR(39)
         WHEN 'date' THEN CHAR(39) + '1900-01-01' + CHAR(39)
         ELSE ''
       END + ') then ''''  
 else ' + quotename(Column_Name, char(39)) + ' + '',''' + ' end +'
 from information_schema.columns
```

Comment: I want to check if its datetime and if its null. Please see my edited question

Comment: Then add WHEN 'datetime' THEN CHAR(39) + '1900-01-01 00:00:00' + CHAR(39) to the case

Comment: seems ok but when trigger is fired I get this error: Incorect syntax near ')'

Comment: Could you please provide a full sample of the code which throws the error? Most certainly there is one bracket to much or an aditional comma or something similar.

Comment: Hm... so you start the trigger with "Select [at]sql = [at]sql +"? So basically you extend the empty string [at]sql by itself + the case? Sounds strange...